# What is the regular expression to validate camelCase name?

Tags: regex, camelcasing

I am implementing ESLint [id-match](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-match) rule and I want to enforce [camelCase convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

I have now came up with `^[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)*\d*$` that is used to validate:

```
fooB
fooBar
fooBarBaz
foo123
fooBar123
```

and that does not validate:

```
foo123Bar
foo_bar
foo$
föö
```

Is this a correct regex to validate compatibility with the camelCase convention?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128305/regular-expression-to-identify-camelcased-words see here for more elaborate answers

Comment: @mahatmanich Thank you. Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: For those who will come across this while searching for a regex for ESLint id-match rule, I have ended up using `(^[A-Za-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)*\d*$)|(^[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*(_\d$)*$)|(^(_|\$)$)` rule (https://regex101.com/r/wR5oZ4/3). It validates variable and property names, class names, common utility names (`_` and `$`) and constants. I have shared my entire ESLint rule definition here, github.com/gajus/eslint-rules/blob/master/.eslintrc.