# Regex pattern to match many combinations for a camel case string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, camelcasing

I'm trying to create a regex pattern (one or more). For instance having `SomeCamelStringToCombine` it should match following substrings:

`Some, Camel, String, To, Combine, SomeCamel, SomeCamelString,SomeCamelStringTo, SomeCamelStringToCombine, CamelString, CamelStringTo, CamelStringToCombine, StringTo, StringToCombine, ToCombine`.

I managed to create this pattern: `/(?=([\p{Lu}]+[\p{L}]+))/`, but it matches

`SomeCamelStringToCombine, CamelStringToCombine, StringToCombine,
ToCombine, Combine`.

I don't know whether I should modify it or create extra patterns. The problem is I do not know how. I'm using Java for a matching.

Can I ask you for help or tips?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128305/regular-expression-to-identify-camelcased-words-with-leading-uppercase-letter

Comment: @Arpit: I don't think so, read the question carefully.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here and say you can't do it with *just* a regex. But a regex identifying the pieces combined with a loop to (re)create the combinations should be straightforward enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder apologise for the incorrect comment. And I second you on regex not being the way to do that. Maybe split the string and match with an array of Strings.

Comment: This would be vary expensive to do in regex, and I guarantee you whatever regex you come up with will be wrong in some way. It would be much better to just create a index list of the capital letters in the string, do a nested loop over the list, and take all the valid sub-strings from that. Much easier to do and much less work to make mistakes in.

Comment: I'm confused. What are the inputs? Do you seed it with the string `SomeCamelStringToCombine` and want to *build* a pattern that can only match those specific substrings, given that sample seed?

Comment: To rephrase, I read your question as "E.g. having `SomeCamelStringToCombine` it should match e.g. `CamelString`, but not e.g. `SomeString`". Is that a correct interpretation of your question? Or are you trying to say that having `SomeCamelStringToCombine`, you want to *extract* all the listed combinations from that string, i.e. you're not *matching* anything, but building specific substrings of that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a fixed size regex to find *up to* that many word combinations.
Below uses 5 words worth of captures, but you could extend it to any size.

You could easily create the regex programmatically.

Just exclude *empty* capture groups from the array.

*Note, after the first match, you can also exclude the 1-5 groups to avoid

duplicate singles.*

`(?=([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)?([A-Z][a-z]+)?([A-Z][a-z]+)?)(?=(\1\2))(?=(\6\3)?)(?=(\7\4)?)(?=(\8\5)?)\1`

https://regex101.com/r/ta9Qzq/1

```
 (?=
      ( [A-Z] [a-z]+ )              # (1), required Word 1
      ( [A-Z] [a-z]+ )              # (2), required Word 2
      ( [A-Z] [a-z]+ )?             # (3), optional Word 3
      ( [A-Z] [a-z]+ )?             # (4), optional Word 4
      ( [A-Z] [a-z]+ )?             # (5), optional Word 5
 )
 (?=
      ( \1 \2 )                     # (6), required Word 1,2
 )
 (?=
      ( \6 \3 )?                    # (7), optional Word 1,2,3
 )
 (?=
      ( \7 \4 )?                    # (8), optional Word 1,2,3,4
 )
 (?=
      ( \8 \5 )?                    # (9), optional Word 1,2,3,4,5
 )
 \1                            # Advance position by 1 word
```

Comment: How is this an answer to "e.g. having `SomeCamelStringToCombine` it should match e.g. `CamelString`, but not `SomeString`"?

Comment: @Andreas - In a global match, it produces the array `Some, Camel, String, To, Combine, SomeCamel, SomeCamelString,SomeCamelStringTo, SomeCamelStringToCombine, CamelString, CamelStringTo, CamelStringToCombine, StringTo, StringToCombine, ToCombine` _what's the problem ???  https://regex101.com/r/ta9Qzq/1

Comment: Guess I didn't understand the question. Still not sure I do. However, you say *"it produces the array"*, and it doesn't. At least not without extra Java code to combine all the various captured groups from the repeated `find()` calls. You also say *"you could extend it to any size"*, but that isn't entirely true, since you can extend it to any *particular* maximum size, but not to support *any* (unlimited) size.

Comment: @Andreas  - Nah, I wouldn't put it to code just yet, would you? As for extending the size, it's limited by the amount of capture groups that Java supports. I guess if it supports 25,000, you'd end up with a 2-3 MB regex.

Comment: @Andreas  - Oh, also there is some sort of n-factorial operation going on here. It be hard to imagine _unlimited_ size.

Comment: Yeah, rather than trying to do it all with regex, just split the input into the words, e.g. using `(?<=.)(?=\p{Lu})` *(split before uppercase letter that is not the first letter)*, and then it's a standard combinations problem, easy to implement in Java. [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: @Andreas - Yeah, I would do it that way too. But, some people are adamant. The want to see some cataclysmic, mind bending, hand wringing, head exploding regex... Like this _[175,000 Word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)_. _Now they have 3 problems._