# Test if string is in Upper Camel Case format with only alphabetic characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to test if the following rules apply on a string:

- Must start with uppercase letter.
- Next characters can be either in uppercase or lowercase format.
- Only the following characters are allowed: `A-z`

For instance, a string can be either `String` or `CamelCaseString`, but neither `string` nor `Camel-Case-String` nor `String125`. Numerics and special characters must not exist.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128346/7982356) in a previous post.

```
const isUpperCamelCase = (str) => {
  return /\b[A-Z][a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)*\b/.test(str)
}
```

I have the following test suit that tries to test the above function. Unfortunately, not all tests pass:

```
test('isUpperCamelCase', () => {
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('Button')).toBeTruthy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('GreenButton')).toBeTruthy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('GreenLargeButton')).toBeTruthy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('B')).toBeTruthy()

    expect(isUpperCamelCase('button')).toBeFalsy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('buttonCamel')).toBeFalsy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('Green-Button')).toBeFalsy() // => fail!
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('Button125')).toBeFalsy()
    expect(isUpperCamelCase('Green_Button')).toBeFalsy()
    expect(helpers.isUpperCamelCase('Green+Button')).toBeFalsy() // => fail!
    expect(helpers.isUpperCamelCase('green+Button')).toBeFalsy() // => fail!
})
```

If I include special characters such as `(,)+-` in my string the function evaluates to `true` when it should evaluate to `false`. this happens because there exists a match between the special chars, but this is not the behavior that I want. How can I solve this problem?

*Note: Please add detail explanation in your answer. Thanks! :)*

Comment: Use `/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/`

Comment: @anubhava thanks that seem to work! Please post an answer if you would like! :)

Comment: @anubhava That also matches `CAMELCASE`

Comment: Note that I would not consider AB camelcase, but maybe it matches your definition.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that's a valid camel case string. Consider "pin", as in "personal identification number". You would typically camel case this as "PIN", not "Pin".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You regex needs anchors for matching beginning and ending of the string, not `\b`. So do:

```
/^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$/
```